# Html video playing issue

Tags: html, video, html5-video, video-processing

This is my code

```
<video autoplay loop id="myVideo" >
<source src="video/alliance.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If I add a "muted" attribute to the video tag, then it plays fine but when I remove the muted attribute, the video does not play. How to solve this issue? Because I want to have sound with it.

Comment: Try autoplay="autoplay" instead of the "true" value.

Comment: I didn't use true value. You can see my code. I tried autoplay="autoplay" as you mentioned but it is not working. Still, the problem is the same.

Comment: pass 'muted' as well

Comment: But I want to have sound with it. If I pass muted attribute, then how the sound will be played? Please read the caption I added with the code.

Answer (score 1):

As per Google Autoplay [Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

- Muted autoplay is always allowed.
- Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
  User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
  On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.
  On mobile, the user has [added the site to their home screen].
- Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

Comment: How do I enable the interaction with the domain (click, tap etc) that you have mentioned? Can you please explain this.

Comment: Add a play button and start the video on that play button, or you can add an unmute button if you want an autoplay

Comment: Play button is already there but the purpose of this button is pause/play which is working but I want the video to be auto-played in the start once the webpage loads, with sound as well.